# How can I make a video display in Landscape mode on iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I'm having a very strange problem. I want a video to appear in landscape mode, but I can't seem to make it work. Even if I can't make it always show Landscape, at least I want it to show ok, and I can't make that either!! Here is my code:

```
#import "SplashViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h"

@interface SplashViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
@end

@implementation SplashViewController
@synthesize timer = _timer;

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (id)init
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self = [self initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self = [self initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSString *url = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"intro.mp4"];

    playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];

    [playerViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];

    //play movie
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [player play];
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    removeObserver:self
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:player];
    [player stop];

    [player.view removeFromSuperview];

    [self loadMainView];
}

- (void)loadMainView 
{
    MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainVC animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

And here comes the weirdness...

If I start the app with my iPad physically in Landscape Mode, the video shows like this (please not that the bar at the top is shorter than the widht! :O)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdPUP.png]

If I then rotate the iPad to Portrait, it looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWK68.png]

But then, if I start the app with my iPad physically in Portrait Mode, the video shows like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NXRY.png]

And if I then rotate the iPad to Landscape, it looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW6OK.png]

Which is GREAT! This final image is what I would like the video to always look like.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong???

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Ok, with @Tark answer I was able to fix the player display issue. Now it's showing fine no matter how I start the app. Thanks for that!! What is missing now is the always landscape mode.

I tried with the following methods:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

I also tried inserting the row 
    Initial interface orientation = Landscape (right home button)
In the Info.plist

What I'm getting is that if I start the app in Landscape mode, if I rotate the iPad to Portrait, it stays in Landscape. GREAT!
But if I start the app in Portrait mode, the video shows in Portrait mode. Once I rotate it to Landscape, I can't rotate it back to Portrait, which is good, but I don't want it to start in Portrait!

**EDIT 2**

Ok, now this is even more weird. If I try it on an **iPhone**, it works great. No matter if I start the app in Landscape or Portrait, the video is shown always in Landscape.

But if I try it on an **iPad**, the problem in EDIT 1 arises... :S

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting the frame of the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`s view when you add it as a subview?

```
...
playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
...
```

To make the app only run in landscape mode, you should make sure that you have only selected the orientations you want in the app plist. In Xcode 4 there is a handy Supported Interface Orientations section in the target settings, make sure you only select landscape here. If you still have the issue, you have to make sure that you are disabling autorotation on all visible controllers in the view stack.

[image]

Comment: You're a life saver!! it fixed the player display problem! :D I'm still having the other problem though, which is the title of the question, that I cannot make it display always in Landscape mode. Look at my Edit where I describe a bit further... thanks again! I want to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Yay, I can upvote now, so I just voted your answer. Now if only I could fix the other problem! thanks!

Comment: Tark, sory if it wasn't clear in the post. The app DOES support all the orientations. I just want the video to be shown in Landscape mode. That's why I can't use the option you talk about, as that would prevent the rest of the app to work un Portrait...

Comment: This is a trickier problem. If you are pushing the controller onto a navigation stack, this will not work, if you push in portrait the controller will display in portrait. The only way to get this to work in landscape only mode is to display the controller modally, which will force a rotation event.

Comment: I see... do you have an example of how I can do that? I'll start researching though... What's very strange to me, is that on the iPhone this doesn't happen, no matter how I start it it always display Landscape. I'm only having this problem on the iPad. :S

Comment: @Jan Just do [self presentModalViewController:playerViewController animated:NO]

Answer (score 0):

[shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) is deprecated as of iOS 6, Have you tried using [supportedInterfaceOrientations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations)?

If you are trying to support iOS 5 & 6 then I believe you need to use both:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

I haven't tested this so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: This is giving me the same results as before on the iPad (see EDIT 1). If I start the app in Landscape, then all is good, I can't rotate to Portrait. But if I start the app in Portrait, the video is shown as Portrait... this is driving me insane!